# Stripe connect subscription split fees

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hi i'm using the stripe PHP API to build a platform for a client, the platform is selling monthly subscription to author content on a monthly basis I have a deal with my client to share 50% of the fees we taking on each subscriptions.

I used this snippet to make the subscription:

```
$stripe->subscriptions->create([
  'customer' => '{{CUSTOMER}}',
  'items' => [['price' => '{{PRICE}}']],
  'expand' => ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
  'application_fee_percent' => 10,
  'transfer_data' => ['destination' => '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}'],
]);
```

I was wondering if how i can transfer my half of the 10% automatactly and monthly to an other connected acconunt (mine)... Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the subscription is on the platform, you can transfer funds to multiple connected accounts [after the charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/subscriptions#create-separate-charges-and-transfers).

Alternatively, you can keep the same code you shared here and then transfer the 5% from the application fee to the other connected [account separately](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create). You’d listen to `invoice.paid` [Event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.paid) and when creating the transfer, pass the `source_transaction` [parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/transfers/create#create_transfer-source_transaction) which transfers funds from a charge. These funds will not become available until the original charge is settled.